# How to get user details of user from randomuser API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

In a React assignment, I am trying to get the user details from randomuser.me API and show it on another component. Everything is done except unable to get user details from its id

AdminPanel.js

```
<TableBody>
          {results.map((person) => (

            <TableRow key={person.id.value}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{person.name.first}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{person.name.last}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{person.location.street.name + ',' + person.location.street.number + ',' + person.location.state + ',' + person.location.country  }</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right"><img src={person.picture.thumbnail} /></TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{person.email}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{person.dob.date}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" >
                    <Link style={{color:'white'}} to={`/user-detail/${person.login.uuid}`}>View Details</Link>
                </Button>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>

          ))}
</TableBody>
```

After clicking on link it redirects to another page as

UserDetail

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const UserDetail = () => {
    const {userid} = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/user-detail/${userid}`).then(res=>res.json()).then(result=> {
            console.log(result)
        })

    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Bu, when console log shows this error 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

What mistake I'am doing?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the data that's returned from the API call?

Comment: Which data do you want?

Comment: The data fetch `userid` returns

Comment: OK please wait I'll display above

Comment: Please see above, I've edited

Comment: this endpoint is correct `/user-detail/${userid}`, I think you just cus first of that?

Comment: this endpoint is correct `/user-detail/${userid}`, I think you just cus first of that?

Comment: I'am trying data of user from uuid

Comment: I didn't get it @hamidrezanikoonia

Comment: I think your URL you are passing to fetch is not actual endpoint you need to be requesting.

Comment: OK so how to get user details and what may be the solution?

Comment: ` fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api`) `, your endpoint should like this

Comment: ` fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api`) `, your endpoint should like this

Answer (score 0):

Fetch url

```
fetch (`https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}`). then (d=>d.json()).then(e=>console.log(e))
```

Where seed is a string like

```
const seed ="fea8be3e64777240"
```

Comment: I'am getting different results when I try to put the id  value as seed

Comment: I'am not getting seed value in API

Answer (score 0):

you need to use state for the results

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


export const UserDetail = () => {
    const {userid} = useParams()
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]); 
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/user-detail/${userid}`).then(res=>res.json()).then(result=> {
            console.log(result)
            setResult(result);
        })

    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another free API you can use instead if you are interested in generating random users with details.

API: https://wirespec.dev/Wirespec/projects/apis/Stackoverflow/apis/getUserDetails

Endpoint: https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/getuserdetails?id=100

Wirespec lets you create up to 1 million random users including avatars. Check it out at:

https://wirespec.dev